# Using redux, how to avoid rendering old state data before making a new API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I've just started to do some experiments with `redux` and `react-redux`.

**Note:** I'm using Hooks, so I'm using `useSelector()` and `useDispatch()` custom hooks from `react-redux`.

Imagine I have some piece of state to get a `blogPost` from DB based on a `slug`.

**My state.blogPost:**

```
{
  loading: false,      // TRUE while fetching
  error: null,         // TO keep network errors
  blogPost: null       // TO keep the blogPost
}
```

**BlogPostContainer.js**

I'm dispatching the actions and the async call inside a `useEffect`.

**Note1:** I'm doing the async job manually, cause I'm not using `redux-thunk` yet.

**Note2:** I'm using `react-router-dom` so the slugs come from `props.match.params.slug`.

Example: `myApp.net/blog/some-blog-post-slug`

```
// ...

const { loading, error, blogPost } = useSelector(state => state.blogPost);
const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {

  dispatch({ type: "GET_BLOGPOST_START", payload: props.match.params.slug });  // START ACTION

  mockAPI(props.match.params.slug)

  .then((result) => {
    dispatch({ type: "GET_BLOGPOST_SUCCESS", payload: result });               // SUCCESS ACTION
  })

  .catch((err) => {
    dispatch({ type: "GET_BLOGPOST_FAIL", payload: err });                     // FAIL ACTION
  })

}, [dispatch,props.match.params.slug]);

// RETURN STATEMENT

return (
  loading ?
    <div>Loading...</div>
  : error ?
    <ErrorPage/>
  : <BlogPostPage blogPost={blogPost}/>
);
```

**QUESTION**

This is working fine for the first loaded blogPost (because the state is completely empty at that point).

Now imagine that I go back to the home page an click on another blogPost.

From the second time on, when my `BlogPostContainer` renders, there's already something present in my state (either a `blogPost` or an `error` that was loaded last time for the previous blogPost slug).

And as a result of this, **I see a flicker of that information displayed on screen right before** my `useEffect` runs. When it runs, `loading` will be set to true by the `GET_BLOGPOST_START` action, and I'll see the loading.

I would like to see the loading page immediately. Without any flickering with old state data.

**How do people usually handle this while using redux?**

- Do I need a **local** `loading` state?
- Should I dispatch an action to turn `loading` to `true` when my component unmounts? So it will be already `true` when my component mounts again for the next `slug`?
- Should I use `useLayoutEffect` so the effect will **run before rendering** and I won't see the flickering? (it works, but it feels wrong).
- What is the best solution for this kind of situation?

---

EXTRA

**My reducer:**

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  error: null,
  blogPost: null
};

function getBlogPostReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "GET_BLOGPOST_START":        // SET LOADING TO TRUE
      return {
        ...initialState,
        loading: true
      };
    case "GET_BLOGPOST_SUCCESS":      // SET BLOGPOST and LOADING TO FALSE
      return {
        ...initialState,
        loading: false,
        blogPost: action.payload
      };
    case "GET_BLOGPOST_FAIL":         // SET ERROR and LOADING TO FALSE
      return {
        ...initialState,
        loading: false,
        error: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default getBlogPostReducer;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `useEffect` return a cleanup function that will dispatch a "clear blog post" action when the component unmounts:

```
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch({ type: "GET_BLOGPOST_START", payload: props.match.params.slug });  // START ACTION

  mockAPI(props.match.params.slug)

  .then((result) => {
    dispatch({ type: "GET_BLOGPOST_SUCCESS", payload: result });               // SUCCESS ACTION
  })

  .catch((err) => {
    dispatch({ type: "GET_BLOGPOST_FAIL", payload: err });                     // FAIL ACTION
  })
  
  return () => dispatch({ type: "CLEAR_BLOGPOST" });

}, [dispatch,props.match.params.slug]);
```

And the reducer handler should remove both `error` and `blogpost` entries from the state:

```
case "CLEAR_BLOGPOST":
  return initialState;
```

Comment: Thanks! Is this a common practice? Or do people usually use this "caching" behavior to avoid extra fetching? I can keep a list of previously fetched blogPost and check if there's alredy one for my slug before fetching. What do you think?

Comment: Cleanup is a common practice when the state might be large, or is not reusable. Caching is a common practice when you thing that people will the content multiple times. If you want to cache blogposts, you should keep each blogpost under a different key (the slug maybe). However, since you load it from a server, the web browsers caching might work for you, and you want need to manage a cache yourself.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @cbdeveloper I think this must be accepted as answer.

Comment: @SuleymanSah I really like the answer and I agree. But since I asked this question on a weekend, I'm waiting a little longer to see if anyone has a different approach to this. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this. This is really helpful!